# Android SQLite (1) no such table: viewing error

Tags: android, sqlite

I know there are a few answers out for this issue but i still can't seem to get mine to work. i get error message;

```
04-17 11:35:35.086    2437-2437/com.chris.cv10aajproject E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1)   
AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
04-17 11:35:35.090    2437-2437/com.chris.cv10aajproject E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1)
no such table: viewing
```

my code looks like this:

i have a `InsertData` method in my adapter that is called by my app

```
public long insertData(String posCode,String firstLine ,String town,String county, int roomNum,
                       int askingPrice, int currentOffer, int agreedPrice, String agentName,
                       String agentPhone,String estateAgentNam, int refurb, String Time)
{

    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(DbHelper.POST_CODE, posCode);
    contentValues.put(DbHelper.FIRST_LINE,firstLine);
    contentValues.put(DbHelper.TOWN,town);
    contentValues.put(DbHelper.COUNTY, county);
    contentValues.put(DbHelper.ROOM_NO,roomNum);
    contentValues.put(DbHelper.ASKING_PRICE,askingPrice);
    contentValues.put(DbHelper.CURRENT_OFFER, currentOffer);
    contentValues.put(DbHelper.AGREED_PRICE,agreedPrice);
    contentValues.put(DbHelper.AGENT_NAME,agentName);
    contentValues.put(DbHelper.AGENT_PHO_NUM, agentPhone);
    contentValues.put(DbHelper.ESTATE_AGENT_NAME,estateAgentNam);
    contentValues.put(DbHelper.REFURB_COST,refurb);
    contentValues.put(DbHelper.TIME_OF_APPOINTMENT,Time);

   long id = db.insert(DbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    return id ;
```

my on create method looks like this

```
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
            Message.message(context, "onCreate called");

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Message.message(context, ""+e);
        }
    }
```

and the `CREATE_TABLE` is a constant that looks like this:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + UID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + POST_CODE + " VARCHAR(255)," +FIRST_LINE+" VARCHAR(255)," + TOWN + "  VARCHAR(255)  " +
            "" + COUNTY + " VARCHAR(255) ," + ROOM_NO + " INTEGER ," + ASKING_PRICE + " INTEGER , " + CURRENT_OFFER + " INTEGER , " + AGREED_PRICE + "INTEGER , " + AGENT_NAME + " VARCHAR(255)," +
            "" + AGENT_PHO_NUM + " VARCHAR(255), " + ESTATE_AGENT_NAME + " VARCHAR(255), " + REFURB_COST + " VARCHAR(255), " + TIME_OF_APPOINTMENT + " VARCHAR(255));";
```

Please any advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table is not created because your `CREATE TABLE SQL` command is wrong.

You should add space between `Column Name` and `Column Type`

```
TABLE_NAME + " (" + UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, // add space before INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

### Corrected:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + POST_CODE + " VARCHAR(255)," +FIRST_LINE+" VARCHAR(255)," + TOWN + "  VARCHAR(255)  " +
        "" + COUNTY + " VARCHAR(255) ," + ROOM_NO + " INTEGER ," + ASKING_PRICE + " INTEGER , " + CURRENT_OFFER + " INTEGER , " + AGREED_PRICE + " INTEGER , " + AGENT_NAME + " VARCHAR(255)," +
        "" + AGENT_PHO_NUM + " VARCHAR(255), " + ESTATE_AGENT_NAME + " VARCHAR(255), " + REFURB_COST + " VARCHAR(255), " + TIME_OF_APPOINTMENT + "  VARCHAR(255));";
```

Comment: Thanks guys i made the changes you suggested and now i get a different error code ( altho it now creates the database) so i think it may be one of my inserts 
the new error message is 
    04-17 12:12:04.710    2730-2730/com.chris.cv10aajproject E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "county": syntax error
04-17 12:12:04.718    2730-2730/com.chris.cv10aajproject E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such table: viewing

Comment: @BeginnerJavaDev After doing this you must uninstall your app and again install a fresh .apk built

Comment: Btw just wanted to say thanks for all the help guys really appreciate it and amazing response time :D

Comment: @BeginnerJavaDev We are always here for helping!!!! Appreciated your response !!!!

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a space between `UID` AND `INTEGER`

So change

```
 " (" + UID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
```

to

```
 " (" + UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
```

and

```
"INTEGER , " + AGENT_NAME +
```

to

```
" INTEGER , " + AGENT_NAME +
```

So rewrite create table statement as

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + POST_CODE + " VARCHAR(255)," +FIRST_LINE+" VARCHAR(255)," + TOWN + "  VARCHAR(255)  " +
            "" + COUNTY + " VARCHAR(255) ," + ROOM_NO + " INTEGER ," + ASKING_PRICE + " INTEGER , " + CURRENT_OFFER + " INTEGER , " + AGREED_PRICE + " INTEGER , " + AGENT_NAME + " VARCHAR(255)," +
            "" + AGENT_PHO_NUM + " VARCHAR(255), " + ESTATE_AGENT_NAME + " VARCHAR(255), " + REFURB_COST + " VARCHAR(255), " + TIME_OF_APPOINTMENT + " VARCHAR(255));";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add space and you are missing a comma in TOWN so do the following:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + POST_CODE + " VARCHAR(255)," + FIRST_LINE + " VARCHAR(255)," + TOWN + "  VARCHAR(255),  "  + COUNTY + " VARCHAR(255) ," + ROOM_NO + " INTEGER ," + ASKING_PRICE + " INTEGER , " + CURRENT_OFFER + " INTEGER , " + AGREED_PRICE + "INTEGER , " + AGENT_NAME + " VARCHAR(255)," + AGENT_PHO_NUM + " VARCHAR(255), " + ESTATE_AGENT_NAME + " VARCHAR(255), " + REFURB_COST + " VARCHAR(255), " + TIME_OF_APPOINTMENT + " VARCHAR(255));";
```

Comment: add a comma after VARCHAR for Town and see as I have shown.